# AngularJS replace element in list via foreach

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to replace an element in a list by a new one (data). The list is in my scope as $scope.list.

So I do something like that :

```
angular.foreach($scope.list, function(element) {
    if(element.id === data.id) {
      element = data;
      console.log(element);
      return false;
});

console.log($scope.list);
```

In the console element is updated but $scope.list remains unchanged.

First I tried to use Array.find() instead of looping the list like this :

```
$scope.list.filter(x => x.id === data.id)[0] = data;
```

But I got an error in the console : Invalid left-hand side in assignment.

Do you know why it doesn't change the $scope.list ? I am quite new in AngularJS and JavaScript.

Thanking you in advance,

Comment: `element=data` is only changing a variable in memory. You need to change the value of the array element at the index where the id's match

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
$scope.list = $scope.list.map(element => element.id === data.id ? data : element);
```

A map function is basically a forEach with return - [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

Without arrow function and proper if

```
$scope.list = $scope.list.map(function(element){
  if (element.id === data.id){ 
    return data;
  } 

  return element;
});
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It works pretty good now ! I assume it's better to do this way or, as someone said above, to loop and then update the list at the correct index ?

Comment: I think this is the best way as it is a functional programming way. I think for loops should be prohibited :D

Answer (score 0):

Use the `key` and `obj` values exposed to the iterator function:

```
angular.forEach($scope.list, function(element,key,obj) {
    if(element.id === data.id) {
      obj[key] = data;
      console.log(obj);
      return false;
});
```

For more information, see [AngularJS angular.forEach function API Reference](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.forEach).